# Example of $2$ nonisomorphic simple graphs satisfying conditions.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, graph-theory, contest-math

What is an example of $2$ simple graphs which:

1. have the same degree sequence;
2. for any $n \ge 2$ have the same number of copies of $K_n$;
3. for any given $k \ge 3$ have the same number of induced copies of $C_k$

but nonetheless are not isomorphic to each other?

Answer (score 1):

If I’m not mistaken, the graphs below work: degree sequence $4,4,2,2,2,2$, eight copies of $K_2$, two copies of $K_3$, no copies of $K_n$ for $n>3$, two induced copies of $C_3$, one induced copy of $C_4$, no induced copies of $C_n$ for $n>4$. The graphs are not isomorphic, since the two vertices of degree $4$ are adjacent in one and not in the other.

[image]